# See if bootstrap checkbox is checked asp.net c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I need to get true or false if bootstrap check-box is checked on server side

This is the control:

```
<div id="CheckCategoria" runat="server" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="ChkInspecao" OnClientClick="return false;" Text="Inspeção" UseSubmitBehavior="False" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-check" />
    <asp:Button ID="ChkHipot" OnClientClick="return false;" Text="Hipot" UseSubmitBehavior="False" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-check" />
    <asp:Button ID="ChkCalibracao" OnClientClick="return false;" Text="Calibração" UseSubmitBehavior="False" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-check" />
    <asp:Button ID="ChkChecagemInterna" OnClientClick="return false;" Text="Checagem Interna" UseSubmitBehavior="False" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-check" />
    <asp:Button ID="ChkRevisao" OnClientClick="return false;" Text="Revisão" UseSubmitBehavior="False" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-check" />
</div>
```

as they have `runnat="sever"`, I can get them on server-side but how can I see if it's toggled or not?

I tried:

```
string Inspecao = ChkInspecao.Attributes["checked"];
```

but it's returning null.

how can I do that?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using buttons instead of <asp:CheckBox /> ?

Comment: Because it's more beautiful. let's say it's another kind of CheckBox.

Comment: Buttons and CheckBoxes are two different things which serve two different purposes. I'd suggest making them CheckBoxes and then using something like http://arthurgouveia.com/prettyCheckable/ to style them.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if Bootstrap didn't support styling checkboxes to look like buttons. jQuery UI seems to be able to. EDIT: [It does in 3.x at least.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-examples) It's not documented for 2.3.2 but it seems to work right.

Answer (score 0):

You can make beautiful checkboxes with Jquery, please check this page:
[ChackBox UI Jquery](http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox)

---

Anyway, this is a how:

```
 <script  type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".btn").click(function () {

            //The old selected gets unselected
            $(".Selected").addClass("NoMore");

            //This won't 
            $(this).removeClass("NoMore");

            //Because this is the one selected
            $(this).addClass("Selected");

            //Take the tab selected
            $("#ValSel").val($(this).attr("id"));
            return false;
        });
    });
</ script>
<asp:HiddenField ID="ValSel" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

Then, from code-behind:

```
Label1.Text = ValSel.Value;
```

This is the style I used (but it is not important):

```
<style>
.Selected
{
    color:Green;
}
.NoMore
{
    color:Red;
}
</ style>
```

I imagine you would change the background color, but I insist, you can use the checkboxes from the Jquery UI.